# Alternate rows of 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I alternate rows from two tables?

```
SELECT table1.a, table1.b, table1.c FROM table1
UNION
SELECT table2.a, table2.b, table2.c FROM table2
```

I want this result:

```
a    |   b   |    c   |
first row table1
first row table2
second row table1
second row table2
....
```

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` instead

Comment: Which column provides an order by which to call a row first or second?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say *first row table1* and *second row table1*, it implies that you have some order in your query, otherwise the order is not important. You can create a fake column with a value for table1 and another value for table2, and then use this fake column in the order. Let's say your original order is by the `a` column:

```
SELECT 1 AS original_table, table1.a, table1.b, table1.c FROM table1
UNION
SELECT 2 AS original_table, table2.a, table2.b, table2.c FROM table2
ORDER BY a, original_table
```